# What's the efficient inverse-operation of numpy.array_split?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm working on cross_validation to choose hyperparameters,and I split my training data into k folds.Take one folder as my validation data,the others as training data(I will do that for `k` times in fact).

```
X_train_folds = numpy.array_split(X_train,k)
```

The `X_tran_folds` will look like this:`[subarray1,subarray2,.....]`

The subarrays have the same number of columns.

But how to merge the `k-1` subarrays into one?

Comment: [`numpy.concatenate()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)?

Comment: @pp_ You'are right! I've solve that!
I think `delete` + (`concatenate` or `stack` or `vstack`)  is a proper way to do that!

Comment: Sorry about the silly question,I've just started to use python to program.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`numpy.concatenate()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to join a sequence of arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([0, 1])
>>> b = np.array([2, 3])
>>> np.concatenate((a, b))
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```